# Unable to retrieve ID # in calculated value column

Tags: calculated-column

So I manage to do a calculated value column and incorporate it with the default ID # SharePoint assigns on each list entry.

However, I notice that there are a few that it was not done so.

please see screenshot.
[image: missing ID#]

Answer (score 1):

When you first create an item the ID is not allocated until it is written back to the list.  The calculated column is calculated before the item is written back to the list and so the ID does not exist at that time.

If you later edit the item then the formula will calculate the column correctly.

An alternative I have used in the past is to use a workflow.  As this is triggered when the item is written to the list then the ID value is available and can be used to construct another value in the same way as a calculated column.

Comment: This is my experience as well, utilizing the ID column in a calculated column is very inconsistent and you should use workflow to set the field instead.